# How can I get an HTTP response body as a string?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons

I know there used to be a way to get it with Apache Commons as documented here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html

...and an example here:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/416.html

...but I believe this is deprecated.

Is there any other way to make an http get request in Java and get the response body as a string and not a stream?

Comment: Since the question and all the answers seem to be about apache libraries, this should be tagged as such. I don't see anything without using 3rdparty libs.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574478

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Every library I can think of returns a stream. You could use [`IOUtils.toString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to read an `InputStream` into a `String` in one method call. E.g.:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);
```

**Update:** I changed the example above to use the content encoding from the response if available. Otherwise it'll default to UTF-8 as a best guess, instead of using the local system default.

Comment: this will corrupt text in many cases as the method uses the system default text encoding which varies based on OS and user settings.

Comment: @McDowell: oops thanks, I linked the javadoc for the method with encoding but I forgot to use it in the example. I added UTF-8 to the example for now, although technically should use the `Content-Encoding` header from the response if available.

Comment: Actually charset is specified in contentType like "charset=...", but not in contentEncoding, which contains something like 'gzip'

Comment: Do I have to close the InputStream?

Comment: this   function causes  the input stream  to  be closed, is there a  way @WhiteFang34 i  can print  my  response   and  continue  to  use the http  entity

Comment: this is link for apache commons https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0

Answer (score 338):

Here are two examples from my working project.

1. Using [`EntityUtils`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) and [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html)

   ```
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
   System.out.println(responseString);
   ```
2. Using [`BasicResponseHandler`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html)

   ```
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
   String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
   System.out.println(responseString);
   ```

Comment: The only problem I faced with method 1 is, the entity object is consumed when you do `response.getEntity()` and it is now available as `responseString`. if you try to do a response.getEntity() again, it'll return `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Worked in my case - getting body from CloseableHttpClient response.

Comment: What is httpClient?!

Comment: @AndreasL. httpClient is of type HttpClient ( org.apache.commons.httpclient package)

Comment: Its so common to get the response content as string or byte array or something. Would be nice with an API directly on Entity to give you that. Having to look for this to find this util class.

Comment: I upvoted. Please consider adding the full "imports" statements.

Comment: Worth noting that the first method will get you the response body regardless of the HTTP status, whereas the second method throws exception for non-2xx HTTP statuses.

Comment: How would you retrieve the response body for non-2xx HTTP statuses?

Comment: I am getting "Attempted read from closed stream." error while using body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: You should add how you've instantiated `httpClient` as its not necessarily clear to all readers

Answer (score 53):

Here's an example from another simple project I was working on using the httpclient library from Apache:

```
String response = new String();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j", request));
HttpEntity requestEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(mURI);
httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
if(responseEntity!=null) {
    response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
}
```

just use EntityUtils to grab the response body as a String.  very simple.

Answer (score 30):

This is relatively simple in the specific case, but quite tricky in the general case.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.getContentMimeType(entity));
System.out.println(EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity));
```

The answer depends on the `Content-Type` [HTTP response header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header#Responses).

This header contains information about the payload and *might* define the encoding of textual data. Even if you assume [text types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text), you may need to inspect the content itself in order to determine the correct character encoding. *E.g. see the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2) for details on how to do that for that particular format.*

Once the encoding is known, an [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) can be used to decode the data.

*This answer depends on the server doing the right thing - if you want to handle cases where the response headers don't match the document, or the document declarations don't match the encoding used, that's another kettle of fish.*

Comment: how to get it as HashMap ? I get response as Json, how to read that?

Answer (score 11):

Below is a simple way of accessing the response as a String using Apache HTTP Client library.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;

//... 

HttpGet get;
HttpClient httpClient;

// initialize variables above

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpClient.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

Answer (score 10):

The Answer by McDowell is correct one. However if you try other suggestion in few of the posts above.

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
if(responseEntity!=null) {
   response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
   S.O.P (response);
}
```

Then it will give you illegalStateException stating that content is already consumed.

Answer (score 9):

How about just this?

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://www.someurl.com/"));
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the below code also to get the HTML Response in java

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //  args[0] :-  http://hostname:8080/abc/xyz/CheckResponse
    HttpGet request1 = new HttpGet(args[0]);
    HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(request1);
    int code = response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response1.getEntity().getContent())));) {
        // Read in all of the post results into a String.
        String output = "";
        Boolean keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing) {
            String currentLine = br.readLine();

            if (currentLine == null) {
                keepGoing = false;
            } else {
                output += currentLine;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Response-->" + output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good response, this is what I need to display, the response after posting data to the server. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vanilla Java answer:

```java
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;

...
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(targetUrl)
  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
  .build();
HttpResponse response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
String responseString = (String) response.body();
```

Comment: One correction! `.uri(URI.create(targetUrl))`, not `.uri(targetUrl)` !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lightweight way to do so:

```
String responseString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < response.getEntity().getContentLength(); i++) { 
    responseString +=
    Character.toString((char)response.getEntity().getContent().read()); 
}
```

With of course `responseString` containing website's response and response being type of `HttpResponse`, returned by `HttpClient.execute(request)`

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code snippet which shows better way to handle the response body as a String whether it's a valid response or error response for the HTTP POST request:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
OutputStream os = null;
String payload = "";
try {
    URL url1 = new URL("YOUR_URL");
    HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString().getBytes());
    os.flush();

    String line;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConnection.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        if(reader == null)
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConnection.getErrorStream()));
    }
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        payload += line.toString();
}       
catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Post request Failed with message: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson to deserialize the response body, one very simple solution is to use `request.getResponseBodyAsStream()` instead of <strike>`request.getResponseBodyAsString()`</strike>

Answer (score -1):

Using Apache commons Fluent API, it can be done as mentioned below,

```
String response = Request.Post("http://www.example.com/")
                .body(new StringEntity(strbody))
                .addHeader("Accept","application/json")
                .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .execute().returnContent().asString();
```