# Is it possible to get both the status code and the body content when using Apache HttpClient's Facade?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

I am using [Apache's HttpClient Fluent Facade in Java](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fluent.html#d5e834) in some sample code for developers to extend.  They really like the fluent facade, with its capability to just call:

```
this.body = Request.Get(uri.build()).execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Additionally, I could get the status code by callling:

```
this.statusCode = Request.Get(uri.build()).execute().returnResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Unfortunately, there are several instances where I need the status code in addition to the body.  Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024625/how-to-get-httpclient-returning-status-code-and-response-body), I see that I could have them learn the HttpClient object -

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
String body = handler.handleResponse(response);
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

but, that means initializing the HttpClient object and seemingly rejecting the Fluent interface and the Request.Get (or Post) syntax.  Is there a way to get both the status code and the body *without* losing the Fluent syntax and without making two discrete calls?

Comment: I have added this to the jira board for the project https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1581

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is, though you'll have to handle the Response object yourself.  Here's an example of how I've done it in the past:

```
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = Request.Get(url)
    .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
    .socketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
    .execute()
    .returnResponse();

int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
byte[] serializedObject = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
```

There are several methods to retrieve the body content using EntityUtils.  In this case I was retrieving a serialized object from a cache, but you get the idea.  I really don't believe this is a departure from the Fluent API, but I guess that's a matter of opinion.  The problem is that using the Fluent returnXXX methods, the response is fully consumed and closed so you have to get the things you need from the response itself.

Comment: just a nitpick: with HC fluent there is no need to call EntityUtils#consume.

Comment: What is the full class name of the HttpResponse?  (i.e. what do I need to import to get this to work?)

Comment: org.apache.http.HttpResponse.  You should always check the API docs: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html