# Java Apache HttpComponents, how to read POST response?

Tags: java, apache, post

I am using HttpComponents in Java to POST login information to a website. After I log in, I would like to send more POST data, depending on the webpage returned. I am unsure how to actually print out or view the html/webpage that the server returns as a result of sending my POST data (perhaps what I am looking for is the response body?).

All the tutorials only seem to show how to view header information or server codes. I think it is probably something simple I am missing. It is possible that perhaps I do not understand this process well.

My code so far:

```
public class httpposter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://hroch486.icpf.cas.cz/cgi-bin/echo.pl");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "vip"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "secret"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        try {
            System.out.println(response2);
            HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
            // do something useful with the response body
            // and ensure it is fully consumed
            EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
        } finally {
            httpPost.releaseConnection(); }} }
```

Comment: Erm ... see the comment that says "Do something useful with the response body" ? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html

Comment: `response2.writeTo(OutputStream);` does that even compile? Using `getContent()` is more appropriate in most circumstances. Of course what is in the response depends on the service (and possibly the request headers).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That is exactly what I am trying to do, but I am unsure of how to access it. All the response seems to have is header information.

Comment: @owlstead I am very embarrassed no that part of the code I was playing around with at the last minute. Sorry I removed it.

Comment: @owlstead What do I call getContent() on? HttpResponse doesn't seem to have a method named getContent(). Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: this is a good reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you copied and pasted this code?

```
HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
// do something useful with the response body
// and ensure it is fully consumed
EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
```

Javadocs are your friend: [HttpEntity Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html)

The `IOUtils` makes this even easier:

```
String body = IOUtils.toString(entity2.getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time trying anything like this and I am little clueless. Yes, it was copied and pasted, and I was trying to figure out how to use it. I did try to read the javadocs before I posted but this was not an obvious solution to me. Thanks again!

Comment: see response here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string