# Get httpresponse from HttpClient

Tags: java, http

Is there a way to extract `HttpResponse` from `HttpClient()` and `GetMethod` in java?
I need the `HttpEntity` from the response using `HttpClient`.
Anyone knows a way?
My code :

```
client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(URL);
        get.setDoAuthentication(true);
        try{

            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(get);
            //parsing XML from response
            //System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());
            if(statusCode == 200){
                System.out.println();
              // here I need HttpResponse object to get HttpEntity
            }


        }finally{
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: Post your full code, and please do so quickly before your question gets voted down.

Comment: May be this post will be helpful for you > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java

Comment: No. As one client can process a number of requests and therefore deliver a number of responses, there is no direct relation between the client ant the data or requests respectively. You may access the body over the URLConnection object. Why are you limited to the HttpClient?

Comment: due to Credentials.  how can I access the body?

Comment: Do you need to add credentials? That is a different question. You cannot add credentials to the body using GET. You will need to send a POST request then. When it is for HTTP basic auth then you could add credentials to the URL which I strongly discourage. (The URL is not crypted but the body is when using HTTPS.)

Comment: I solved that. yes that works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(URL);
        get.setDoAuthentication(true);
        try{

            HttpResponse response = client.executeMethod(get);
            //parsing XML from response
            //System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                System.out.println();
              // here I need HttpResponse object to get HttpEntity
              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader
                  (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              String line = "";
              while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                  textView.append(line);
              } 
            }
        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
```