# How to read Network Response (PAYLOAD) from GET API call using Java

Tags: java, rest, api, httpurlconnection

I want to read the Network Response after API GET call using

```
URL obj = new URL("https://URLGoesHere");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Refer attached image to understand what actually I want to read in Response 
after API GET call.

[image]

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5769756/6689101

Comment: @zombie Yes I did, It no were related to the question.
I will give me HTML of the page