# Java Post request with form data

Tags: java, post, postman

I want to make a simple POST call in Java,
I am getting a 200 response code but, with the wrong response message,
I am told there is a different way to make a Post call when using a **form data**.
**Following is my current Java code to make the post call -**

```
private String makePostCall(){
        try {
            String url = "http://someIp/trusted";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            // add header
            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "app_user"));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return result.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Following is the Post call sample that is working through Postman app -**
[image]

**I am referring the following website -**
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

The expected outcome of the post call is supposed to be a Token ie. a String value, current response is -1.

Comment: What's the question? give expected vs actual result

Comment: The expected outcome of the post call is supposed to be a Token ie. a String value, current response is -1.

Comment: what is the status code of `response`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java

Comment: I am getting a 200 response but, I am told I am passing the form data ie. app_user the wrong way or something, check the Postman screenshot.

Comment: U able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 7):

These answers are correct, but I struggled to get this to a working code. So, let me provide a general and working answer which can be reused.

```java
private static RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().build();

public HttpResponse postWithFormData(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) throws IOException {
        // building http client
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        // adding the form data
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();

// add any number of form data
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_key_1", "form_value_1");
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_key_2", "form_value_2");

// Getting the HTTP Response and processing it
HttpResponse response = postWithFormData("http_url", urlParameters);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
// String of the response
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
// JSON of the response (use this only if the response is a JSON)
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

These are my main imports, in case anyone gets confused on what to import.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
```

Comment: What is your `requestConfig` ? On line 3

Comment: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig

Comment: Worked for me with some slight changes as per my use case. Thumbs up.

Comment: Functional example with all required imports and dependencies on replit, fill in your URL/data. https://replit.com/@domjancik/JavaFormDataPost

Answer (score 4):

Give a try by setting content type `multipart/form-data` explicitly,

```
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

In your code ,

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters)); 
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```