# Send Push Notification to Android mobiles from my Java Web Server

Tags: java, push-notification

Can any one tell me the detailed process to send push notifications from my web page to Android mobile. I am using Springs Hibernate & JSP's.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not having your own Android app you can use a personal notification hub/app like [Notify17](https://notify17.net).

What you would do is:

- [Create](https://dash.notify17.net/) a Notify17 account, it's free.
- Download the [app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hydex11.notify17&hl=en).
- From the dashboard, [create a raw API key](https://dash.notify17.net/#/rawAPIKeys).
- From your server, send a request to the raw API key endpoint ([API reference](https://notify17.net/docs/api-endpoints/#raw-notifications)).

E.g. in `curl` format:

```sh
curl -X POST \
  "https://hook.notify17.net/api/raw/RAW_API_KEY" \
  -F title="Instance setup: finished" \
  -F content="Instance ${HOSTNAME} has been set up correctly!"
```

You can use any Java library/method to make the same request:

- [Java Post request with form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687553/java-post-request-with-form-data)
- http://zetcode.com/java/getpostrequest/
- https://www.edureka.co/community/5406/how-to-send-http-post-requests-on-java