# how to read message from post request in java

Tags: java

```
...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

I send a post request, then it will send back a message. How should I read the message back from the post request.

thx

Comment: Please post an example of the response body you get back as well as any attempts you have tried.

Comment: `InputStream inputStream = response.getContent();`

Comment: thx, it works. I use respose.getEntity().getContent()

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to read the response, that means you are reading body in the response.

1. Using `EntityUtils` and `HttpEntity`

   ```
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
   System.out.println(responseString);
   ```
2. Using `BasicResponseHandler`

   ```
   String responseString = new
   BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
   System.out.println(responseString);
   ```

Same is answered in the below post:
[How can I get an http response body as a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java)