# HttpResponse response String has extra `"` and doesn't recognize `\n`

Tags: java, httpresponse, spark-java

I have a class that implements Route interface (package spark) that is supposed to return a String in the `handle` function. When I convert the response to String I have two extra `"` in the beginning and the end of my String and the `\n` is not recognized as 1 char in my String but rather as 2.  Does anyone know the fix?

This is the code and `response` is an instance of `HttpResponse`:

```
Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
String output = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```

The next Assertion fails

```
Assert.assertEquals(10, output.length());
```

```
Java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :10
Actual   :13
```

And according to `System.out` output is

```
"123456789\n"
```

While it should be `123456789` and a `\n` at the end of it but I don't believe `\n` should be shown in `System.out.print()`

Comment: Have you looked at what's in the HTTP response on the wire with something like Wireshark or Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what solved it for me at the end, if anyone else has the same problem:

```
String output = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
String content = new Gson().fromJson(output, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(responseString);
```

Reference from - [How can I get an http response body as a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769717/how-can-i-get-an-http-response-body-as-a-string-in-java)